# Reading EditText dynamically from onclick listner get error android.widget.CheckBox cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: android

I have created a dynamic android view and added checkboxs and Edit texts on it, Check the following code.

In this code down 'list2' having values{a,b,c....}

```
List<Integer> checkBoxIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> editTextIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int id  = 0;
    int id1 = 0;
    CheckBox ck;
    TextView txtWt;


        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
         LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
         ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         sv.addView(ll);

         for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
         {           
             ck = new CheckBox(this);
             ck.setId(id);
             checkBoxIdList.add(id);
             ck.setText(list2.get(i));
             ll.addView(ck);         


             txtWt = new TextView(this);
             txtWt.setText("Weight");
             txtWt.setTag(list2.get(i));
             txtWt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             ll.addView(txtWt);

             edtWt =  new EditText(this);
             edtWt.setId(id1);
                 editTextIdList.add(id1);
             ll.addView(edtWt);
             id++;
             id1++;
         }
         Button btnSubmit = new Button(this);
         btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
         ll.addView(btnSubmit);
         this.setContentView(sv);
```

I am trying to read both the values of check box and Edit text on button click as follows

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxIdList.size(); i++) {

                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkBoxIdList.get(i));
                    String text = chk.getText().toString();


                }

                for(int i = 0; i < editTextIdList.size(); i++) {
                    try{ 
                        EditText edtWt = (EditText)findViewById(editTextIdList.get(i));
                        String text = edtWt.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       Log.e("pass 1", e.toString());
                   }
                }

            }
        });
```

While using this I am getting values of checkbox as a,b,c correctly. But while reading EditText I am getting an error like this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.CheckBox cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

But I am reading it after filling EdiText only. Why this error coming? How can I solve it?? Please help me guys.

Comment: You're setting the same ids for your CheckBox and your EditBox.

Comment: Both are different ids, see the code id for check box and id1 for EditText

Comment: The value is the same. You start `id` and `id1` both at `0` and increment them. So the first round, you're running `setId(0)` on both, second iteration is `setId(1)`, etc.

Comment: Dude there is no XMl layout its created dynamically

Comment: aaa yeah.... my mistake.

Comment: @androidsuckzzz actually your code suckzzz, initially `id1` will be `0` which is set to `edittext` and in first turn of for loop `ck.setId` will be `0` also because `i = 0`.

Comment: @323go dude you are right, I changed id1 to 100 and its working fine. Ty dude

Comment: Sure, I'm adding an answer with a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in comments, you are setting duplicate ids for your various elements. It's the value that counts, not the variable you use to set the id. That said, you'd be better off using references to your views rather than the ids. See below:

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxIdList = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
List<EditText> editTextIdList = new ArrayList<EditBox>();
    CheckBox ck;
    TextView txtWt;


        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
         LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
         ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         sv.addView(ll);

         for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
         {           
             ck = new CheckBox(this);

             checkBoxIdList.add( ck );
             ck.setText(list2.get(i));
             ll.addView(ck);         


             txtWt = new TextView(this);
             txtWt.setText("Weight");
             txtWt.setTag(list2.get(i));
             txtWt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             ll.addView(txtWt);

             edtWt =  new EditText(this);
             editTextIdList.add( edtWt );
             ll.addView(edtWt);
         }
         Button btnSubmit = new Button(this);
         btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
         ll.addView(btnSubmit);
         this.setContentView(sv);
```

Then access it directly:

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxIdList.size(); i++) {
                String text = checkBoxIdList.get(i).getText().toString();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < editTextIdList.size(); i++) {
                try{ 
                    String text = editTextIdList.get(i).getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Log.e("pass 1", e.toString());
               }
            }

        }
    });
```